# UIViewTableCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath is calling but not pushing a view controller

Tags: iphone, ipad

so im having a UIViewController view with a UITableView.
So the UIViewController class name is SelectionScreen.
The UITableView class name is SelectionScreenTable.

Picture:
http://img717.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20100609atpm0.png/

I have declared a UITableView *selectionTable in SelectionScreen class and connected it to the xib file of the SelectionScreen

what the problem is , is that when i click a row in the table,it stays selected as highlighted blue, it calls the didSelectRowAtIndexPath (checked with NSLog) but not pushing a new view which is called(GraphView).

This is the code which i use to call the new controller WHICH WORKS with a normal button

```
GraphView *aSelectionScreenViewController = [[GraphView alloc]
         initWithNibName:@"GraphView"
         bundle:nil];
```

[self presentModalViewController:aSelectionScreenViewController animated: YES];
 [aSelectionScreenViewController release];

I searched around and found that I need to set a delegate for the table in the UITableView class itself on the viewload

```
tableview.delegate = self;
```

or

```
self.tableview.delegate = self;
```

But it was not working. the controller was still not being pushed, and yes i have checked the controller is not nil as i tried it with a simple button.

So i was thinking whether i should set the delegate of the UITableView at the UIViewController instead, so i tried this code

```
selectionTable.delegate = selectionTable.self;
```

but obviously it did not work =\, it messed up the whole UITableView and caused all the cells to be its predefined settings.

So does anybody have any idea on how i can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it instead of using 
presentModalViewController.

i used an animation to bring in the view instead 
More info in the link below
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13427-uiview-slide-transition.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to get the full picture here, but I can try some hints.

The outlets seem to be correctly connected from the screenshot, although Selection Screen Table could probably be called Selection Screen Table Controller and the class name should be SelectionScreenTableController for less confusion.

I think the problem could be that the method presentModalViewController: must be called on an active view controller to work.

From what I can tell you have three view controllers, a SelectionScreenTableController, a GraphViewController, and then there must also be some kind of main controller, probably SelectionScreenController.

The SelectionScreenController is the active view controller, so that must be the one to have sent the presentModalViewController: message.

There are several ways you could solve this. The quick fix would be to make an outlet in SelectionScreenTableController called selectionScreenController and link it to File's Owner in the nib file (assuming your SelectionScreen class is in fact a view controller), then call:

```
[selectionScreenController
    presentModalViewController:aSelectionScreenViewController
    animated: YES];
```

instead in your current listing of didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering! i tried ur code and now it looks like this

 GraphView *aSelectionScreenViewController = [[GraphView alloc]
             initWithNibName:@"GraphView"
             bundle:nil];

[selectionScreenController
  presentModalViewController:aSelectionScreenViewController
  animated: YES];

No idea whether its what your talking about but its not working, :( forgive me if im doing anything wrong. 
Here are some sshots to show the xib connections
http://img10.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20100609atpm0.png/
http://img268.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20100609atpm0.png/

Comment: Hm, but now you seem to have moved the outlets and changed the class assignments from the first post.

The outlets seemed fine before, but now you say file's owner should be of class SelectionScreenTable and that the table view controller should be of class SelectionScreen, and you can't just switch those around like that.

If you want to try what I ment to explain, you have to move the classes and outlets back to the way it was, then in your SelectionScreenTable class add an outlet:
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SelectionScreen *selectionScreen;
(not enough room)

Comment: However, I'm not sure how you want things to look in the app itself, if you mean for the selection screen to only hold the table, then get rid of the SelectionScreenTable orange thingy in your nib altogether and make File's Owner of class SelectionScreenTable instead. Then put all your code in SelectionScreenTable.m instead of spreading it between SelectionScreen.m and SelectionScreenTable.m

Comment: hmm actually i want the SelectionScreen to hold the selectionScreenTable, then on clicking a row, it will push a view called graphView that sorts of overlaps the whole selectionScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, i solved it, in the screenshot

http://img717.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20100609atpm0.png/

The SelectionScreenTable controller in the XIB of SelectionScreen,  the view outlet was not connected to the XIB in the SelectionScreen XIB, so i guess it wasn't properly configured.